Got attribute error when trying creating model
I got this error message
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field id on serializer IngredientSerializer.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the Ingredient instance.
Original exception text was: 'Ingredient' object has no attribute 'ingredient'.
when trying to save model in DRF.
My serializers:
from django.db import transaction
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Recipe, Ingredient, RecipeIngredient, Tag


class IngredientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Ingredient.objects.all, source="ingredient")
    amount = serializers.IntegerField()

class Meta:
    model = RecipeIngredient
    fields = ["id", "amount"]


class CreateRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True)
    tags=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(...)
    image = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    name = serializers.CharField(source="recipe_name")

class Meta:
    model = Recipe
    fields = ["name", "image", "text", "cooking_time", "ingredients", "tags"]

def create(self, validated_data):
    ingredients_data = validated_data.pop("ingredients")
    tags_data = validated_data.pop("tags")

    with transaction.atomic():
        recipe = Recipe.objects.create(**validated_data)
        recipe.tags.set(tags_data)

        recipe_ingredients = [
            RecipeIngredient(
                recipe=recipe,
                ingredient=ingredient_data["ingredient"],
                amount=ingredient_data["amount"],
                )
                 for ingredient_data in ingredients_data]

        RecipeIngredient.objects.bulk_create(recipe_ingredients)

    return recipe


And my models here

class Ingredient(models.Model):
  
    ingredient_name = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_LENGTH_200)
    measurement_unit = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_LENGTH_200)



class Recipe(models.Model):

    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through="RecipeIngredient", related_name="recipes")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, related_name="recipes")
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,                            related_name="recipes")
    recipe_name = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_LENGTH_200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="recipes/images/")
    text = models.TextField()
    cooking_time = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=                      [MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(50000)])


class RecipeIngredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="recipe_ingredients")
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="ingredients")
    amount = models.PositiveIntegerField()



I can't understand what the problem might be, I tried to write both on the usual serializer and as above with the help of ModelSerializer, but I get the same error.
Using django 3.2.25 if that matters in this case.
I would be grateful for any help

Please format the code properly.

Is this answer your question

You use recipe_ingredients as source for the ingredients, not ingredients, so:
class CreateRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientSerializer(many=True, source='recipe_ingredients')
    tags = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Tag.objects.all(), many=True
    )
    image = serializers.ImageField(required=False)
    name = serializers.CharField(source='recipe_name')

    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ['name', 'image', 'text', 'cooking_time', 'ingredients', 'tags']
